# CSL showing author-date inline but numbers for citation

Tags: markdown, bibtex, bibliography, citations, csl

Writing in markdown and using bibtex for referencing.
I am wondering if there is a CSL style (or another way to do it) that would show author-date when citing inline but numbers when adding a reference to a sentence. For exemple:

Bob et al. (2019) showed that blabla, but another study [2] also showed that blabla... (both references being in the bibliography).

Any thoughts? Is it bad practice? Should I write the "Bob et al." manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible in CSL, which does not make a distinction between narrative (Smith (1776) says) and regular (Smith 1776) citations, though different tools offer some options when working with author date styles. (e.g., when working in markdown [using pandoc/citeproc for CSL](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-syntax), you can use `@smith76` to create Smith (1776) and `Smith says [-@smith76]` for "Smith says (1776)".

When working with a numeric style as in your example, your only option, though, is to manually write the author. What you would want as output in any standard style, though, is *not* "Bob et al. (2019) showed" but "Bob et al. [1] showed"